# Accessing key values?

Tags: d3.js

This is probably a very simple thing to do but haven't been able to figure it out. I have a multi-line graph with a legend.  I have specified the parameter_id as the key as per format below.

```
Array[3]
0: Object
key: "1"
values: Array[11]
0: Object
client_id: "1"
dateTimeReceived: "2013-03-12 05:54:10"
dateTimeTaken: Tue Mar 12 2013 05:53:41 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
id: "1"
inspectionPoint_id: "1"
parameterType: "Temperature"
parameter_id: "1"
reading: 2.1
testSourceLocationDescription: "test source"
testSourceLocationLatitude: "53.000000000000000"
testSourceLocationLongitude: "-7.000000000000000"
testSourceLowerLimit: "4"
testSourceUpperLimit: "25"
testSource_id: "1"
unitMeasurement: "°C"
__proto__: Object
```

The problem I have is that obviously the legend text is displaying the id - but I would like it to display the parameterType.  Do I need to specify the parameterType as a second key (would like to avoid this if possible) or is there any way of accessing this value?

PS - I initially used the parameterType as the key but elements weren't being bound properly on update.

Comment: How are you generating the graph?

Comment: Gist here - https://gist.github.com/Majella/ab32fe0151fd487da3f6

Comment: Have you tried changing the line under legend.append('text') from ".text(function(d){ return d.key; })" to ".text(function(d){ return d.parmaeterType; })"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change line 72 in your gist from

```
.text(function(d){ return d.key; })
```

to

```
.text(function(d){ return d.values[0].parameterType; })
```

Comment: Thanks but I'd already tried that and doesn't display any text at all when change to d.parameterType

Comment: Ok, now I don't understand your question anymore. The code works fine for me as-is -- see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rgsbY/).

Comment: As said above when I changed the key previously to parameterType the data wasn't being bound properly when updated  -  the lines were jumping all over the place with each update which is why I bound the data to an id.  In your example it's not just the text function that you've changed to parameterType but the key - which works when the graph is static but not when updating.

Comment: I haven't changed anything, I've simply taken the code in your gist. Can you post a link to the code you're having the problem with?

Comment: Sorry!  That wasn't the latest gist I'd posted the link to https://gist.github.com/Majella/ab32fe0151fd487da3f6

Comment: Could you update the JSON as well please? There's no parameter_id in this data.

Comment: I've updated the solution. This is slightly hacky, but works as long as there's something to draw :)

Comment: I didn't update the jsfiddle, but I've updated the answer above -- it's still a simple change.